# Position DIV relative to containing DIV Without Moving Other Stuff

Tags: html, css

[I'm not sure if this question has been asked, though I've looked around a bit.]

I have a DIV inside a DIV. I would like the inner DIV to have a certain position inside the outer div. I'm having some success with this

`position: absolute; top: 0px;right:0px;`

but all other divs are getting moved around. I just want it to `float` on top of the other stuff (float didn't work, of course).

Thanks!

**Edit:** The outer div is relative, and I'd like the inner to move with it when the browser is resized.

**Edit:** Sorry, I've figured out the question (but not the answer): if I use right:0px, the inner div stops moving relative to the outer div and starts moving relative to the browser window. Why would that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` on the inner element. If your outer element is relatively positioned like you say, you can set the position based on the top-left of the outer element.

Comment: that's what I think too, but it's not working. I'll have to track this down, apparently, it must be that I'm misrepresenting what's happening in the code :)... thanks

Comment: "If your outer element is relatively positioned like you say." It was not. I thought that CSS defaults to relative, but that's not the case. Thanks again.

Comment: @yar: No, CSS defaults to "static", so any absolute element will be positioned from the top left of the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply relative positioning to the outer div

Then absolute positioning to the inner div, your inner div will position relative to the outer div.

(top:0; left:0 will be where ever the top left of our outer div is.

```
<div>other Div</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top: 100px;">Abs Div</div>
</div>
```